# I have an issue with adding a function to an array. (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, indexing

This is the code that adds the Function (Canvas Drawing) To the sameTree array

```
let TreesI = 5;
    let sameTree = [];
    let randomValueX = mathR(-20, 20);
    let randomValueY = mathR(-20, 20);
    for (let i = 0; i < TreesI; i++) {
      randomValueX = mathR(-20, 20);
      randomValueY = mathR(-20, 20);
      sameTree[TreesI] = Tree7(randomValueX, randomValueY)
    }
```

But it didn't do anything,

The console.log output gave this

> [5: undefined] (6) = $2

This is a sample of Tree7

```
function Tree7(startWidth, startHeight) {

  ctx.save();
  let treeObj = {
    translateValues: {
      startWidth: startWidth,
      startHeight: startHeight,
      endWidth: -startWidth,
      endHeight: -startHeight
    },
    scaleR: mathR(0.8, 1)
  }

  ctx.translate(treeObj.translateValues.startWidth, treeObj.translateValues.startHeight);
ctx.scale(treeObj.scaleR,treeObj.scaleR);

//ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0, 100, 1)';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
ctx.lineWidth = 0.2;
var reduce = 2;
  //Tree drawing sample under
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0,0);
  ctx.lineTo(mathR(0,10),0);
  ctx.stroke();
  // Tree drawing sample above

  ctx.translate(treeObj.translateValues.endWidth, treeObj.translateValues.endHeight);
  ctx.restore();
}
```

Now after getting some answers I realised that I need to stop updating the random value `ctx.lineTo(mathR(0,10),0);`. The code I have currently just keeps the coordinates. Please help.

Comment: `sameTree[i]` instead of `sameTree[TreesI]`?

Comment: I have different issue now, "[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined] (5) = $2". Do you know what the problem is? I want it to have the function with the values, so I can reuse it on another for loop.

Comment: It would be nice if you post how `Tree7` function looks like.

Comment: I have a Canvas drawing in my function, and it gives random values when I call it so that's why I want to have a same version with it, because I am calling it all the time in my animation and I don't want it to change.

Comment: I can't see any return value from the `Tree7` function which is leading `undefined`

Comment: If you call it Tree7(200,200) in a canvas, It will be drawn at x 200 and y 200.

Comment: The function returns nothing. It's correct that you see undefined

Comment: @Jejun Will I need to return the whole code in the function or how do I do it?

Comment: If you want the results of your function calls stored in your array, your function should return them.
As your function currently has not return statement, it always "returns undefined" when done. Thats why you see undefined in your array

Comment: @TostMaster I tried putting all the values in the Tree7 function like this `function Tree7() { return(//All the values)}` But this gave error.

Comment: You cannot just return multiple values like `return (value1, value2, ...)`. 
A function can only return one value. So you could put all your values you wish to return into an object or an array, and then return that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to store the randomly generated position values and draw.

```
let TreesI = 5;
let sameTree = [];
let randomValueX = mathR(-20, 20);
let randomValueY = mathR(-20, 20);
for (let i = 0; i < TreesI; i++) {
   randomValueX = mathR(-20, 20);
   randomValueY = mathR(-20, 20);
   sameTree[i] = {"x":randomValueX, "y":randomValueY};
   Tree7(sameTree[i].x, sameTree[i].y);
}
```

And when you want to draw with pre-generated values after this,

```
for (let i = 0; i < TreesI; i++) {
   Tree7(sameTree[i].x, sameTree[i].y);
}
```

Comment: Worked for what I asked for, but now I realised I only gave the code to show you for coordinate location x and y. I have random generating code in the Tree7 function, is there any way I can make it give same value it got first time when I call it many times in my Animation function?

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing sameTree[i] instead of sameTree[TreesI] it will work when Tree7(randomValueX, randomValueY)  returns a function.

Comment: So I did this, but technically it worked, but now it says "[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined] (5) = $2"

Comment: How can the function values be inside this array?